# how get CPU current frequency at real time in virtual machine

Tags: linux, cpu, frequency, kvm

Can get the CPU current frequency at real time in virtual machine(kvm or vmware virtual machines).

I can't get that by `dmidecode -t processor|grep -i speed` or `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` or `lscpu |grep 'MHz'` in virtual machine.

But the last two command work well by `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` or `lscpu |grep 'MHz'` in physical machine.

Comment: `I can't get that by...` `But the last two command work well` - decide, does it work or does not "work well"? What does it mean "work well"?  Please post the exact error messages. And if the last two commands work, then just use these commands - why are you writing here?

Comment: The last two command work for physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

That should be done on the host if at all. VM client can't access cpu it was proteceted.